# Json Reads in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I've been trying to use the Reads[A] in Play as discussed in this post.

[Handling JSON requests in Play Framework 2.0 Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426752/handling-json-requests-in-play-framework-2-0-scala)

However, when I tried to do something similar, I ended up getting this error.

object creation impossible, since method reads in trait Reads of type (json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue)models.SomeObject.AnotherObject is not defined

I currently have:

```
package models

object SomeObject {
  case class AnotherObject(val name: String)
  implicit object AnotherObjectReads extends Reads[AnotherObject] {
    def read(json: JsValue) =
      AnotherObject((json \ "name").as[String])
  }
}
```

And I'm using it in the following way:

```
def callFunc = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.asOpt[SomeObject.AnotherObject].map {
    //Logic
  }.getOrElse(BadRequest)
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have it misspelled. The method is called **reads** not read

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads